# How to create arrow over multiple cells in longtable environment?

Tags: longtable, strikeout

[image]

I need to build a table like the image. I have built the table easily but can not get the arrowed lines properly.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163174/table-with-arrows-between-cells

Comment: Alternatively, this seems to be a GANTT diagram, there is a package for that. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfgantt?lang=en

Comment: You can use `tikz` with `tikzmark` for this. Hard to spell this out without having to invent an example, though.